# How to renumber the field value in SQL using SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table, with one Datatype [int] column [**LNITMSEQ**]. The numbers are all unique.
For example,

first row value = 16384,

second row value = 32768 = 16384*2

**Before Delete a record,**

[image: Original]

**After Delete Record**

[image: Renumber]

May I now how to renumber it using SQL Script? I wish to use Store Procedure to call it

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be updating those sort of numbers on a delete. But if you have to, just use an `UPDATE` statement to set the new value. The `ROW_NUMBER` function will help you assign the correct values.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please tag only a single database engine.

Comment: Anyway to Loop all item Query selection and update based on it. It a must to updating the column value [LNITMSEQ] ? I just read ROW_NUMBER function, it look like only updating 1 2 3 4 5.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to re-number your rows as follows:

```
DECLARE @SOP10200 table (LNITMSEQ int);

INSERT INTO @SOP10200 (LNITMSEQ)
    VALUES
    (16384),
    (32768),
    (49152),
    (65536);

DELETE FROM @SOP10200 WHERE LNITMSEQ = 16384;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT LNITMSEQ
        , 16348 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LNITMSEQ ASC) AS NEW_LNITMSEQ
    FROM @SOP10200
)
UPDATE cte SET LNITMSEQ = NEW_LNITMSEQ;

SELECT *
FROM @SOP10200
ORDER BY LNITMSEQ;
```

Returns (ignoring the other columns which aren't relevant):

| LNITMSEQ |
| --- |
| 16348 |
| 32696 |
| 49044 |

Comment: Thanks for give me a suggestion on it. Ur one can run successfully. Just now i use other script. Keep give me an error. I not so familiar with the code.

Comment: .The script i put it give me an error "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses"SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEMNMBR) 
 row_num, 
    SOPNUMBE, 
    LNITMSEQ, 
    ITEMNMBR
FROM
    SOP10200    --TABLE NAME


update SOP10200
set LNITMSEQ = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEMNMBR)  * 16384

WHERE 
 SOPNUMBE ='MBO0000002' --COLUMN VALUE

Comment: Thats why you have to do it the way I showed you with an updatable CTE (you can also use a subquery), why did you change the update statement?